# Spread array into new array of another type

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, spread-syntax

I've an array of Files (from an input file type) and want to concat them in another array with a different type, but with a File property.

The File array

```
const files:File[];
```

The final array type:

```
export type AttachmentModel = {
    ID?: number;
    Title?: string;
    ServerRelativeUrl?: string;
    File?: File;
}

const attachments:AttachmentModel[];
```

I've tried to use the spread syntax to merge them, but of course the types are different, so this doesn't work:

```
const merged = [...attachments, ...files]
```

If it was only a single object I would have done like this:

```
var testFile: File;
var testeAttachment: AttachmentModel = { ...{ ...testFile, File: testFile } };
```

How can I use "destructuring" in the `files` array so it returns an array of type AttachmentModel?

Comment: use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Well even without knowing how to do that, what would you expect from your code ? Shouldn't you link the attachements and the files together ? What's the linking key ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to end up with a array of `AttachmentModel`. If so, you'll want to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your `File` object to `AttachmentModel` objects:

```typescript
const merged: AttachmentModel[] = [
    ...attachments,
    ...files.map((file) => ({File: file}))
];
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMwJYRDQC4AxfEAbQF0BuAKDpAA8AHJGLDATxYQEEMGKGAAWAWxAoMAWSSgI8ALzwA3nXgb4ASQAiAfiLwUAVzEAjEDHqb4AFVwYCB+Jhi4UAc2uaAypYBulgBKINAYuIEAqjAQzq7uXuqaZE6GKSD0AL4MoJCwCMjoWFCCwuKSGMQCQqISUrLy1PR0hZjwEjAeIMCG1WV1MnKh1ErwFAB0kyU15VJoADTwk+N4BGjjYlAsABTbqyAAlEoAfPDbKumG+5kHB7R0QA)